# Existence of Conditional Density Function

Tags: probability-theory

In probability, there are examples when for two random variables $X$ and $Y$, there does not exist any non-negative function that integrates to 1 over the real-plane. For example, if $X$ is Gaussian and $Y=X^2$. In such cases, does it also mean that the conditional densities $f_Y(|x)$ and $f_X(|y)$ do not exist? In the example above, can we not say $f_Y(y|x)=\delta_{x^2}(y)$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac-delta "function".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional distribution $Y \mid X$ is just another univariate distribution, so your question reduces to "when does a density exist for a [univariate] distribution?"

In the example you gave, the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is a constant random variable (with value $x^2$), so you are asking "does a constant random variable have a density?" We do not consider such distributions as having a density because the CDF is not differentiable. The Dirac-delta "function" is defined to have the properties that an alleged PDF of this degenerate distribution would have, but people usually don't consider it a real density function.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an answer to this question (when does a univariate distribution exist?). Suppose I have the cdf $F_X$ of a random variable $X$, are there sufficient conditions that ensure that there is a density function $f_X$ of $X$?

From your answer, am I correct to conclude that discrete random variables do not have a density function since their cdfs are not differentiable? The cdf of a discrete random variable is almost everywhere differentiable though?

Comment: @GA-Student If the question is "when does a *density* of a univariate distribution exist?" then yes differentiability of the CDF is enough. Recall that a density $f_X$ is supposed to satisfy $\int_a^b f_X(x) \, dx = P(a \le X \le b)$. The fundamental theorem of calculus implies that if such an $f_X$ exists, it is the derivative of the CDF.